# how to enable cors on apache?

Tags: apache, slim, httpd.conf

Am trying to enable CORS on apache server.
I've added below in the virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "authorization, origin, user-token, x-requested-with, content-type"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    ServerName www.xxxxx.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.xxxx.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

restarted the server -> service httpd restart
but still didn't work.

i've tried to add the line also to the .htaccess file but with not luck.

I'm using php slim framework, so as suggested by another solution I've added below to my index.php:

```
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    // should do a check here to match $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] to a
    // whitelist of safe domains
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```

and still getting the same exception in the browser:

```
Access to fetch at 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I'm not sure what am missing here exactly,
Thanks.

Comment: Your virtual host is just a redirection to some other site. How do you know it isn't working? It shouldn't make any different since you can't actually retrieve AJAX resources anyway.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://odan.github.io/2019/11/24/slim4-cors.html)?